# how to check if string from element is "valid date formate", "today" or "yesterday" in java

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I'm working on selenium pretty new in automation mobile field, I'm stuck in a situation where I need to verify the list of elements that that date is a valid date formate(mar 10, 2019) or "today" or "yesterday" if anything from these I get into list I should perform further action but I'm not getting anywhere how to compair all these against the string into the list

I have tried through Iterator to get that particular string

```java
List<MobileElement> elementCells ;

        if(b==true) {
            elementCells =  getDriver().findElements(by("collect_elements_cells"));
            label(String.valueOf(elementCells.size()));// ignore this line this is the framework method to print into console 
            Iterator<MobileElement> iterator = elementCells.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                MobileElement strname = iterator.next();

// in this if condition what should be the third parameter to check the string for date formate (mar 07, 2019)
                if (strname.getTagName().equals("today","yesterday",---)) {

                }
            }


            MobileElement option = getDriver().findElement(by("elements_cells"));

            hardWait(2000);
            option.click();
```

Comment: Show the possible values for `tagName`

Comment: what tagNames ?

Comment: Yes, what is the output of `strname.getTagName()`?

Answer (score 1):

In Java [String.equals()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) function takes only one parameter, you will need to amend your code like:

```
if (strname.getTagName().equals("today")) {
    // do what you need for "today"
} else if (strname.getTagName().equals("yesterday")) {
    //do what you need for yesterday
} else {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
    try {
        sdf.parse(strname.getTagName());
        System.out.println("date is valid");
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        System.out.println("Date is not valid: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

See [SimpleDateFormat class JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for above pattern explanation as well as for information on methods and fields.

Also be aware that [using Thread.sleep is an anti-pattern](https://faculty.uoit.ca/bradbury/concurr-catalog/sleep.html), consider using [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) instead to [explicitly wait for elements presence/availability/etc](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/).